# Load all titles and body text from one content type into array

Tags: nodes, 8

I'm working on an input format filter that should work as following. I have a content-type called glossary, the user can fill in a word (title) and description (body). Then there is a content-type article. When a word in the article matches a word in the glossary it should wrap that word with a span. Something like word. I already did a quick and dirty tryout and that worked fine. I already did a speed test and it worked out fine only a delay of 0.2s max.
But now I try to make it as it should and I got stuck.

The way I think this could work is to have an array with all words and descriptions from the glossary content-type in a array. And then search through the text.

So I created a Plugin/Filter/Filtername.php file. In this file I try to load all node from the glossary content-type (as advised) via dependency injection.

What I found is a way to get all nids, via this code added in to my filter class:

```
class FilterName extends FilterBase {
    public function __construct(QueryFactory $entity_query)
    {
        $this->entity_query = $entity_query;
    }

    public static function create(ContainerInterface $container){
        return new static(
          $container->get('entity.query')
        );
    }

    public function process(){
        $query = $this->entity_query
        $query->condition('bundle','woordenlijst');
        $nids = $query->execute();
    }
}
```

So this should give me all nids of the node I'm looking for but how do I get these node loaded to get there title and body text? I found [this](https://docs.acquia.com/article/lesson-62-loading-entities) lesson about entity loading. Which is usefull but there are some deprecated functions used and I have no idea how to combine these to to get een array of titles and body texts.

So what is currently the best method to load nodes and how can I combine this with the code I already have? And am I even on the right path or not, or is there a better/easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is probably a good reason why you want to do this, but I can't think of one. All I can think of is this not being a scalable approach. That said, caching does work in your favor, but that first load is going to be killer. Are you trying to produce a list of node titles and bodies that can be embedded somewhere on a particular page?

Comment: I have a good reason but maybe not the right method :D. What I try to make is a glossary. So I have a content-type called glossary, the user can fill in a word (title) and description (body). Then there is a content-type article. When a word in the article matches the glossary it should wrap that word with a span. Something like <span data-text="field description">word</span>. I already did a quick and dirty tryout and that worked, but no I try to make it as it should and I got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If yau have lots of node's than its difficult load all nodes at a time and also , to get only title and body, its not fair to load complete node.
Rather than load node and get values, we can use select query and fetch required values.

I am using cache concept here, once your query loaded, set it in cache untill any node values changes or any new node creates.
Use node hooks to remove cache for "node_data"
Below is the query:

```
  $nodedata = array();
  // Check cache exists
  $cache_node = \Drupal::cache()->get('node_data');
  if ($cache_node) {
    $array = $cache_node->data;
    $nodedata = json_decode($array, TRUE);
  }
  else {
    // Query for node title and body.
    $connection = \Drupal::database();
    $query = $connection->select('node', 'n');
    $query->leftJoin('node__body', 'b', 'b.entity_id = n.nid');
    $query->leftJoin('node_field_data', 't', 't.nid = n.nid');
    $query->fields('t', array('title'));
    $query->fields('b', array('body_value'));
    $query->condition('n.type', 'glossary', '=');
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
      $nodedata[] = array(
        'node_title' => $value->title,
        'node_body' => $value->body_value,
      );
    }
    // Set Cache.
    \Drupal::cache()->set('node_data', json_encode($nodedata));
  }
  dsm($nodedata);
```

Comment: That's a very fast solution! To remove the cache, you could set a cache tag. Put `['node_list']` as 4th parameter when setting the cache data. Then the cache will be invalidated automatically whenever a node is changed or created.

Answer (score 0):

you can use entityQuery like this for load all nodes of content type.

```
$node_array = array();
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('type', 'woordenlijst');
$entity_ids = $query->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($entity_ids);
 foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $title = $node->getTitle();
  $body = $node->get('body')->getValue();

  $node_array[] = array(
'node_title' => $title,
'node_body' => $body,
);
}
```

Finally you got a array with title and body.Use dpm($node_array);